# finding css of instagram login page

Tags: css, instagram

I am trying to find the css file of instagram login page.but i can't find it!

usually when we view the page source of a webpage we can find the css file in html head .but how find it for instagram login page?

Comment: Why do you want the whole .css file? If you're looking to just copy the styling of elements on the page, then just `inspect element` and view the css attached to the highlighted element.

Answer (score 0):

Instagram uses [**Isostyle**](https://github.com/iiegor/isostyle) CSS plugin and the style sheets are appended with a unique id.

> With isostyle you can use the require() function also with CSS and
>   LESS files. Note that when you use the require function, automatically
>   it will add the stylesheet to the dom with an identifier
>   (data-isostyle-id).

**Instagram CSS with identifiers:**

[image]

*So in the browser, the styles are not visible in a single file but multiple CSS blocks.*

Comment: ok now i copy the page source of instagram login page in a html file and then copy all the style blocks that you said and pasted it between two style tags.but my page does not look like instagram login page!?

Comment: Show the files that you have used as an edit to the question.

Comment: the html file is more than 30000 
Character! i can not add it but i uploaded it here: http://narcoticss.web44.net/index.htm